# How to align a Button to the far right in MUI AppBar?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having trouble understanding how to align items in MUI. I have the following code:

```js
class SignUpForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Button sx={{ justifyContent: "flex-end" }}
                color="inherit" }>Sign Up</Button>
        )
    }
}
```

which is composed by:

```js
class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1}}>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <SignUpForm />
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </Box>
        )
    }
}
```

But unfortunately the content is still staying to the left. Using this resource https://mui.com/system/properties, I might be missing an important CSS concept here. Could anyone enlighten me?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: About why your code didn't work: `justifyContent` should be set in the flex container, not the container item. Try putting `justifyContent: "flex-end"` in the `Toolbar`

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm understanding more bit by bit :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Toolbar` is a flexbox, so you can add a `div` on the left side and set `justify-content` to `space-between` to push the `Button` to the right:

```
<Toolbar sx={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
  <div />
  <SignUpForm />
</Toolbar>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Love it, this also worked. Thank you for the snippet

Comment: This not works when there are 3 and more items in the toolbar.

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure you just need to change `sx={{ justifyContent: "flex-end" }}` to `sx={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}` on the `Button`

Comment: Oh wow, that worked! Thank you!! I need to study more CSS hah

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2024 MUI 5.15

Add this line of code to the position from where you want items to be pushed to right:

```
  {/* -------- All Items below it will be pushed to right-------- */}
  <Box sx={{ ml: "auto" }}></Box>
```

It will add aempty div with left auto margin pushing everything to the right

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone in the future, if you also include where you're importing your components from. Personally, when I encountered the sx not working (realized this was the issue because when I inspected the element says `sx=[Object object]`), it's because I should've been importing `Toolbar` from `@mui/material`, see this [reference](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/28850). Also, I'm using `@mui/material v 5.10.11`. PS. I'm using Auto-import extension on VSCode, hence, the incorrect import from cause.